# Angular - Handle all 'x' of undefined dynamically in component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a wrapper component which `ngFor` a child component. The child component receives in `@input` an object to format and display.
The problem is that sometimes the object is complete and displayed correctly and sometimes the object is almost empty and I have `'x' of undefined` in all formatting methods, which is normal. How and in what good way can we handle all cases of `'x' of undefined` globally. Based on the TypeScript interface maybe ...?

The wrapper component:

```
<div>
  <contact-card *ngFor="let contact of contacts"
                [contact]="contact">
  </contact-card>
</div>
```

The controller of the child component :

```
@Input() contact: Contact;

get fullName(): string {
  return `${this.contact.collaborator.fullName} ${this.contact.collaborator.lastName}`;
}

get country(): string {
  return this.contact.address.country;
}

hasAccess(): boolean {
  return this.contact.access.edit
}
```

The template of the child component :

```
<div>
  <p>{{ contact.id }}</p>
  <p>{{ fullName }}</p>
  <p>{{ country }}</p>
  <div *ngIf="hasAccess">
    <!--  -->
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a minimalist example. The `contact` object may be in the correct case :

```
{
  id: 1,
  collaborator: {
    firstName: 'Jean',
    lastName: 'Pierre'
  },
  address: {
    country: 'France'
  },
  access: {
    delete: false,
    edit: true
  }
}
```

Or :

```
{
  id: 1
}
```

I also have a pipe `defaultValue` which displays a default value if the value is `null` or `undefined` if it can help :

```
<p>{{ fullName | defaultValue }}</p>
```

mais

Answer (score 1):

Your default value pipe can help in the template, but I guess the error is triggered in the class.

You could try to give your child component's input a default value like `@Input() contact: Contact = new Contact();`
This way, the input will never be undefined and its value will change when it is ready.